# How do I unpack a list with fewer variables?

Tags: python

```
k = [u'query_urls', u'"kick"', u'"00"', u'msg=1212', u'id=11']

>>> name, view, id, tokens = k
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

I need to provide 5 variables to unpack this list. Is there a way to unpack with fewer, so that `tokens` gets the rest of the list. I don't want to write another line to append to a list....

Thanks.

---

Of course I can slice a list, assign individually, etc. But I want to know how to do what I want using the syntax above.

Comment: Do you want to ignore the rest of the valueS?

Comment: @anijhaw no i dont. the rest of the list have to be assigned to the tokens

Comment: Also here: [Unpack 1 variable, rest to a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21354645/unpack-1-variable-rest-to-a-list)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In Python 3 you can do this: (edit: this is called [extended iterable unpacking](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/))

```
name, view, id, *tokens = k
```

In Python 2, you will have to do this:

```
(name, view, id), tokens = k[:3], k[3:]
```

Comment: Thanks. No wonder why I can't do `*tokens` it's only in Py3. Thanks. That slice method looks really good. Well, I never knew we could do that in a single line. Yet, it gives me this `ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack`. I am on 2.6.5

Comment: [PEP 3132](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) descries extended iterable unpacking in Python 3.

Comment: Haha. The parenthesis does the trick. Thanks, and @agf thanks!

Comment: Yes, you'll need the parentheses because you need two items on the left, two on the right.

Comment: Folks I have an opposite problem - I have to unpack a list into fewer variables
`a,b,c=my_list` If the list contains 2 variables I want c to retain it's old value. Thanks in advance !