# Unpack 1 variable, rest to a list

Tags: python, iterable-unpacking

I was wondering if this was possible:

```
def someFunction():
    return list(range(5))
first, rest = someFunction()

print(first) # 0
print(rest) # [1,2,3,4]
```

I know it could be accomplished with these 3 lines:

```
result = someFunction()
first = result[0]
rest = result[1:]
```

Comment: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/

Answer (score 47, accepted):

If you are using Python 3.x, it is possible to do this

```
first, *rest = someFunction()
print (first, rest)
```

Read more about it in this [PEP](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/)

In Python 2, the best you can do is

```
result = someFunction()
first, rest = result[0], result[1:]
```

Comment: great, could you post a link to where I can read about the star syntax?

Comment: Seems that it is an "unpack" operator https://stackoverflow.com/a/2921893/11141271